# Strange regex match node.js

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, match

I have a regular expression in node.js which matches some strange things. Look at this:

```js
var regex = new RegExp('(<\?%)|(%\?>)', 'g');
console.log('<tag><?%text%?></tag>'.match(regex));
```

Leads to `[ '>', '%', '%', '>', '>' ]` and I don't understand why.

The purpose was to match `<?%` or `%?>` and it works perfectly fine on https://regex101.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you haven't escaped `\`. It should be `\\`.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> , go in `Console` and paste the following code.

```
var regex = new RegExp('(<\\?%)|(%\\?>)', 'g');
console.log('<tag><?%text%?></tag>'.match(regex));
```

Comment: @SLaks: Your reason is correct. I was showing why OP's code was not working since `\` was unescaped.

Comment: That actually does work though... am I missing something @SLaks?

Comment: @sweaver2112: Ow the damn typo ! Not in good faculties of vision at this time or day.

Comment: @remus: i would guess he's saying that a regex literal makes for a smaller, simpler regex without the need to escape the backslash. I'd probably not make such a blanket statement there, however, as noob's solution seems ok to me.

Answer (score 2):

Your backslashes are being swallowed by string escaping.

You should use a regex literal instead: `/(<\?%)|(%\?>)/g`

Comment: Your badges are breaking CSS. Should inform on Meta !

Comment: Yeah, noob is right, that's like a bug. Also there is another weird thing. SLaks has 500k rep and I never seen him here at all .. Where have you been until now? `:-)`